# Kotlin & Spring (Data): custom setters

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-jpa, setter

I currently am working on a project that uses Spring Boot, written in Kotlin. It has got to be mentioned that I am still relatively new to Kotlin, coming from Java. I have a small database consisting of a single table that is used to look up files. In this database, I store the path of the file (that for this testing purpose is simply stored in the the resources of the project).

The object in question looks as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "NOTE_FILE")
class NoteFile {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    var id: Int

    @Column(name = "note")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    var note: Note

    @Column(name = "instrument")
    var instrument: String

    @Column(name = "file_name")
    var fileName: String
        set(fileName) {
            field = fileName

            try {
                file = ClassPathResource(fileName).file
            } catch (ignored: Exception) {
            }
        }

    @Transient
    var file: File? = null
        private set

    constructor(id: Int, instrument: String, note: Note, fileName: String) {
        this.id = id
        this.instrument = instrument
        this.note = note
        this.fileName = fileName
    }

}
```

I have created the following repository for retrieving this object from the database:

```
@Repository
interface NoteFileRepository : CrudRepository<NoteFile, Int>
```

And the following service:

```
@Service
class NoteFileService @Autowired constructor(private val noteFileRepository: NoteFileRepository) {

    fun getNoteFile(id: Int): NoteFile? {
        return noteFileRepository.findById(id).orElse(null)
    }

}
```

The problem that I have is when I call the `getNoteFile` function, neither the constructor nor the setter of the constructed NoteFile object are called. As a result of this, the `file` field stays null, whereas I expect it to contain a value. A workaround this problem is to set the `fileName` field with the value of that field, but this looks weird and is bound to cause problems:

```
val noteFile: NoteFile? = noteFileService.getNoteFile(id)
noteFile.fileName = noteFile.fileName
```

This way, the setter is called and the `file` field gets the correct value. But this is not the way to go, as mentioned above. The cause here could be that with the Spring Data framework, a default constructor is necessary. I am using the necessary Maven plugins described [here](https://www.baeldung.com/kotlin-jpa) to get Kotlin and JPA to work together to begin with.

Is there some way that the constructor and/or the setter does get called when the object is constructed by the Spring (Data) / JPA framework? Or maybe should I explicitly call the setter of `fileName` in the service that retrieves the object? Or is the best course of action here to remove the `file` field as a whole and simply turn it into a function that fetches the file and returns it like that?

Comment: I would choose none of the options. Instead, I would remove this ugly transient file property, use the entity only as an entity, used to implement the persistence model of the app, and to represent a row of the database table and nothing more. Then write a service or a top-level function that allows getting the File from a file name. Note that classpath resources, if they're bundled in a jar file (which is usually the case in production), are not files. So representing classpath resources using a File is not a good idea.

Comment: This seems like a better way to go, I agree. Eventually these files will not be classpath resources, as this indeed will not work too well in production, so it might be wise to already look into creating a service that can do the lookup of the files themselves from the database entities.